# Can I connect Inductive Proximity sensor to two different input PLCs

Tags: power-supply, current, proximity-sensor, inductive, plc

[image]

Please, I´d like to know if I can connect a inductive proximity (PNP output) sensor in 2 PLCs inputs like the example in the image attached?

Comment: Depending on the electrical noise present between those two PLC's, shielded cable may be a really good idea.

Comment: Please list the model number of the proximity sensor

Answer (score 1):

Yes if both use the same logic levels and shared gnd.. Only 1 Pull-up to Vcc required. This assumes the input impedance of both is >10 greater than the R pullup.

Comment: Tony, very good...thanks so much for your collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use the sensor to activate a relay and wire the PLC inputs through 2 NO contacts.

Comment: Oh...yes, perfect...Excellent example. Thanks a lot Icecl.